why it always results zero regardless of an example for optimal value
I have coded the multy commodity flow problem using MIP and CPLEX solver but for any example I provide it leads to 0 as optimal value. I believe the problem lies within either in objective function or in the definition of auxilary variable Z which is defind to convert the continues variable x * binary variable y.
import pulp
class MultyCommodityFlow:
def __init__(self, I,J,K,c,f,r,d,s,M,w1,w2,w3,w4):
    # Sets
    self.I = I  # Set of source nodes
    self.J = J  # Set of destination nodes
    self.K = K  # Set of commodities
    
    # Parameters
    self.c = c  # Cost of transporting one unit of commodity k from source i to destination j
    self.f = f  # Fixed cost for using the route from source i to destination j for commodity k
    self.r = r  # Revenue generated from transporting one unit of commodity k from source i to destination j
    self.d = d  # Demand for commodity k at destination j
    self.s = s  # Supply of commodity k at source i
    self.M = M

    #initialize the problem
    self.problem = pulp.LpProblem("MultyCommodityFlow", pulp.LpMinimize)

    #decition variables
    self.x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", [(i,j,k) for i in self.I for j in self.J for k in self.K], lowBound=0, cat = pulp.LpContinuous)
    self.y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", [(i,j,k) for i in self.I for j in self.J for k in self.K], cat = pulp.LpBinary)
    self.v = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("v", [(j,k) for j in self.J for k in self.K], lowBound=0, cat = pulp.LpContinuous)
    self.z = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("z", [(i, j, k) for i in self.I for j in self.J for k in self.K], lowBound=0, cat=pulp.LpContinuous)

def build_model(self):
    #objective func
    self.problem +=pulp.lpSum(self.c[i, j, k] * self.x[i, j, k] for i in self.I for j 
                    in self.J for k in self.K - pulp.lpSum(self.f[i, j, k] * self.y[i, j, k] for i in self.I for j in self.J for k in self.K)          
    
    #contraints
    #1. Flow conservation at source nodes
    for i in self.I:
        for k in self.K:
            self.problem += pulp.lpSum(self.x[i,j,k] for j in self.J) <= self.s[i,k]
    #2. Flow conservation at destination nodes
    for j in self.J:
        for k in self.K:
            self.problem += pulp.lpSum(self.x[i,j,k] for i in self.I) == self.v[j,k]
    
    # 3. Definition of z (auxiliary variable for product of x and y)
    for i in self.I:
        for j in self.J:
            for k in self.K:
                self.problem += self.z[i, j, k] <= self.M * self.y[i, j, k]  
                self.problem += self.z[i, j, k] <= self.x[i, j, k]  
                self.problem += self.z[i, j, k] >= self.x[i, j, k] - self.M * (1 - self.y[i, j, k])  
    #4. Linking x and y with big M
    for i in self.I:
        for j in self.J:
            for k in self.K:
                self.problem += self.x[i,j,k] <= self.M * self.y[i,j,k]
    # 5. Definition of v (amount of demand served at each destination)
    for j in self.J:
        for k in self.K:
            self.problem += self.v[j, k] == pulp.lpSum(self.x[i, j, k] for i in self.I)

def solve(self):
    # Solve the problem
    self.problem.solve(pulp.CPLEX_PY(msg=True))
    
    # Print the status of the solution
    status = pulp.LpStatus[self.problem.status]
    print("\nObjective Value:", pulp.value(self.problem.objective))
    print("Status:", status)
    
    # If the solution is feasible, print the values of the decision variables
    if status == 'Optimal' or status == 'Feasible':
        print("\nDecision Variables:")
        # for v in self.problem.variables():
        #     print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
    else:
        print("No feasible solution found.")


You always get zero because your problem is minimizing the operating cost but you are missing the revenue in the objective function and therefore the system chooses all zeros to make the cost equal to zero.
Furthermore, it seems to me that you do not need z variable at all.
So the overall message is to go again through the code and constraints and see if they are written in a correct way
